# Privacy issues with email providers

Tags: email, privacy, legal, logging

I am looking for an email provider (or for a way to do it myself) that will not divulge my personal information under no circumstances. I found out that getting this information with a order for example, is not that difficult and companies such as Google (Gmail) are required by law to comply. Is there a company that will not give my personal information when asked so by a lawyer? Not because they don't want to (again, not sure if it's possible) but because they delete all the info's related with my account when the session ends (e.g. logs, ip address etc.).

Also, what is the best way to approach this matter? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by personal information?  The associated user profile, the messages themselves, etc?

Comment: @SteveS any personal information you can think of that can identify you.

Comment: Asking for "a list of products/services to do XXX" is offtopic, and would be closed as "too localized", please see the [FAQ](http://security.stackexchange.com/faq). However the second part of the question, how to approach this (together with the focus of some of the answers: other aspects) is a much better question. Please edit accordingly, and refocus the question.

Comment: Related: [opt-out of Gmail contextual adverting](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/8408/396)

Answer (score 8):

I'm not so sure you are attacking this from the right direction.

- Trusting a 3rd party means you are already at risk
- Assembling a lot of data at one point is a huge risk
- Connecting to a 3rd party means they might have logs of IP addresses (like your connection to get email and SMTP senders)

**Very Paranoid**

If you want to be truly paranoid, you would want encrypted and signed emails, an anonymous account somewhere, and a way to hide your IP address using a proxy (maybe TOR?).  You would also want your senders to carry out the same steps so you can't be tracked down via them.  As you get more paranoid, you might want a different email address for each sender, and still more yet.

(i don't have time to write more, but i think there might be some good compromises to make it usable and more private)

Answer (score 5):

You can set up your own domain and even better on your own server. The main problem with e-mail is that even if your inbox is completely safe when you send or receive an e-mail it can be routed almost any way to reach its destiny. On any of those intermediate points the e-mail can be intercepted, read, stored or even modified. So you'll never have perfect security unless you use PGP (or similar) to encrypt your mail. [Perfect security is just a manner of speaking, you'll never get that anyway...]

Any step you take away from Gmail will improve your privacy (such as your own domain, your own server, your owner server at home with your own static IP ...).

Comment: However, it is probably worth noting that even *you* can be subject to court orders just as much as any other e-mail provider.

Comment: @Iszi That's true. But at least you'd know about it. Also if you were really paranoid you could delete all your e-mail after reading it whereas on Gmail or similar you have no guarantee they won't keep backup copies stored somewhere.

Comment: Yes, but turn the paranoid dial up a noch more and you need to think about the copies of your e-mails which are stored on the recipients' or senders' servers.

Comment: @Iszi Definitely. But I can't really see what you want to do about that. I guess stop using e-mail LOL. Anyway for someone to get all your e-mail traffic he'd have to find all your recipients and then get the mails from them ( = a lot of effort).

Answer (score 3):

A service which offers a 10 min disposable email can be found here:

http://10minutemail.com/10MinuteMail/index.html

I havent used it myself but the site says:

"10MinuteMail.com does NOT keep logs or records of your personal data including, but not limited to, your IP address, your incoming e-mail, and your outgoing e-mail.

Your privacy is very important to us.

A temporary cookie is used to allow the service to deliver the e-mail to the right person, but will expire when you close your browser."

Comment: That is nice and very similar to mailinator. I, however was looking for something to use as a primary email address.

Comment: If you have a primary email address, that is a fixed point of data. Which give an investigator somewhere to start to identify you. The usage depends on how anonymous you need to be.

Answer (score 1):

Any email provider could work for this given proper email encryption and reasonably anonymous/false identification information.  Not getting the data and getting heavily encrypted data are nearly the same thing.  It could divulge contact information, but not content.  If you need even more anonymity, you might be interested in mixminion.

Answer (score 1):

Email is extremely difficult to secure. You may find a provider who will refuse to disclose your mail, but that doesn't mean it won't be disclosed (perhaps in some other way or by some other provider).

If you want your communication to be secure, use a secure communication channel. You can get secure with email using S/MIME or PGP/GPG... though some information will always leak such as headers or the fact that you actually DID send an email.