# What Gmail features should be Opted-Out to prevent PII from being indexed?

Tags: email, privacy

The Massachusetts and Nevada PII laws require all email with SSNs or other personally identifying information to be encrypted (TLS or otherwise).

Of the free email providers, GMail does support TLS but they also index the message contents to provide contextual advertising through AdSense.

If we were to recommend our clients of Hotmail (doesn't support TLS) to use GMail, we also want to include instructions on how to opt out of whatever indexing is done within the GMail product.

> What procedures need to be followed to ensure that a GMail user's PII data is protected and not published into any index?

Comment: Hotmail supports SSL/TLS. Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: Last time I checked a few months ago, Hotmail didn't send me messages via TLS.  I assumed this was bidirectional in this case.  I should check again.

Comment: It isn't clear which problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @curiousguy  By opting out of indexes, my intent is to retain as much control as possible over personal information that resides within a particular gmail account.  Does this help?

Comment: Not really. The intent of a webmail with huge storage space like Gmail is to keep the emails on "the cloud" (in cleartext), to be able to search them... Why would you even consider using Gmail?

Comment: Perhaps "indexes" is the wrong word, I just want control over how my information is used.  Adsense, adwords, 3rd part marketing, etc.

Comment: For those not familiar with PII, here's the Wiki:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personally_identifiable_information  Even something as simple as your full name alone could be considered PII.  (Mine probably would be.  John Smith, not so much.)  Researchers have shown that very few details are really necessary to uniquely identify an individual.  According to Wiki:  "...in 1990, 87% of the population of the United States could be uniquely identified by gender, ZIP code, and full date of birth."

Comment: The simple solution is that using Google Mail to send personal information is not a valid solution.  If you are worried about the ability for Google to parse the emails then you must use some other provider that indicates this WILL NOT happen and meet the other qualifications and requirements.

Comment: FYI, I work in a major *.edu environment where we use Google Apps. But, we have a legal agreement with Google *not* to index our content. So, it is possible, but it takes some time. For my personal domain, I've asked about this to their Sales reps and got nothing but silence. But, it really should be something anyone using their services could OPT-OUT of. I don't know what they actually do, but I'm guessing it's a very complex combination of keyword searching, matching demographics, trends and all sorts of valuable statistics can be farmed from private material, collated and used for a variety

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to opt-out from Gmail indexing.
Also I would expect that emails are not stored encrypted on google server/database.

What you can try to do is to send PII data not in email body but as encrypted attachment (for example password protected PDF or Zip file), that way google will not be able to decrypt it and index it.

Aaron

Comment: "_Also I would expect that emails are not stored encrypted on google server/database._" Anyway, since Google would handle the encryption key, encryption wouldn't give you much. I still don't understand the question anyway.

Comment: I thought that indexing meant shared to 3rd parties... that was a mistake on my part and I updated the question

Answer (score 11):

Social Security / tax numbers should never ever **ever** be sent by e-mail in plaintext. 
It doesn't matter if the E-mail is sent via SSL/TLS, you cannot guarantee that an e-mail will remain encrypted throughout it's life. (You can almost guarantee that it won't be)

I don't know what "personally identifying information" really means, but absolutely no information that could be use for identity theft should be included in an e-mail.

1. No CC numbers.
2. No SSN/TID.
3. No "security question" answers. (mother's maiden name and the likes)
4. Driver's license number
5. etc.

If you absolutely must send this information by e-mail it should be in an encrypted attachment.

Comment: Although I agree with this in theory, it doesn't work for all business process in reality.  Sometimes normal end users are conducting a business transaction by email and can't (won't) work with encrypted blobs.  In addition, I don't take responsibility for an email throughout its life, its only within my borders.  I'm not my brother's keeper, though I will support an encrypted payload as you describe.  Unfortunately some customers have mobile devices or use a web client that don't support SMIME, or various other encryption schemes.

Comment: One more thing, some email partners prohibit encrypted payloads if they are supervised by law, or financial regulations (Smarsh)

Comment: Why do normal end users need to see the pieces of information I referenced? And they made prohibit encrypted payloads.. but you're not suppose to be sending this type of information by e-mail at all.

Comment: Signed copies of Life insurance forms include HIPPA PII as an example.  Other industries have different practices and needs

Comment: Is there a reason you can't simply include a link to the document which will be downloaded over ssl?

Comment: Filtering based on security questions is just not feasible.  If your mother still uses her maiden name, then her sig might include it.  If part of your family still lives in the town in which you were born, then it is going to appear in family members' sigs.

Comment: @Mike, I didn't mean to imply that it should be filtered out. These emails shouldn't contain this type of information by nature. However, if it includes your mother's name which happens to be her maiden name.. or the town you were born because you someone lives there, thats different. I guess the point is that it shouldn't contain your mother's maiden name for the sake of identification of yourself. Any other reason is fine. (ie it should never identify your mother's maiden name as such or the town you were born in as such.

Comment: @user606723, I had thought you were talking about policy for mail providers, but I see it's recommendations for email users.  Makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

> how to opt out of whatever indexing is done within the GMail product

Gmail and most other modern webmail systems are built around indexing.  There is no way to prevent the mail service provider from indexing your email.

Even if your users were able to opt-out of each feature, to avoid indexing they would have to opt out of core features including search and spam filtering.  They would also have to opt out of marginal features such as automatic translation.

Could you provide some background on why **indexing** presents a threat to PII in your scenario?  Would you agree that if an index is

1. stored within the same privacy cordon as the raw content (for example, subject to the same encryption on disk and readable only by the same principles)
2. can only be accessed with the same keys/credentials as the raw content
3. does not outlive the raw content

it does not, by itself, increase your risk of PII exposure.

Comment: For some reason I wrote "indexing" when I meant share to 3rd parties.  For some reason I thought they were the same thing.

Comment: @makerofthings7, I understood indexing to mean creating an internal table mapping words to documents that contain them.  [Indexing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_text_search#Indexing): "The indexing stage will scan the text of all the documents and build a list of search terms, often called an index, but more correctly named a concordance. In the search stage, when performing a specific query, only the index is referenced rather than the text of the original documents."

Answer (score 2):

If you want Personally Identifiable Information to remain private, then you can't put it on the Internet. Really, that's the only way.

The laws you mentioned are something of a nonsencial visceral reaction to the recent privacy media scare, and aren't really a reflection of security, reality, or sensible policy.

Instead, if you don't want your name to be made public through Gmail, then don't give Gmail your real name. If you don't want your email address to be public, then don't use email -- because in the very act of using it, you're publicizing it, and it *will* be indexed somewhere; either by Google, Yahoo, Yandex, Lycos, or any one of dozens of public data repositories.

Now, I'm not saying ,"[you have no privacy, get over it](http://www.wired.com/politics/law/news/1999/01/17538)." Instead I'm saying that if you interact in a public medium, you can't expect everyone to forget who you are. You *can* have privacy as long as you are meticulous about not sharing any information that you want to keep private.